# Should Command-M work to minimize when there is no Window system menu?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

In my app, I just noticed that when I press Command-M on the keyboard nothing happens (i.e. the window does not minimize down to the taskbar, although clicking on the Minimize button still works fine). In other apps in MacOS when I press Command-M the `Window` system menu (which contains the Minimize menu command) is momentarily highlighted and then the window minimizes down to the taskbar.

My app's main window has no `Window` menu (per my client's requirements) - is this why Command-M is not working? If so, is this behavior documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

> My app's main window has no `Window` menu (per my client's requirements) - is this why Command-M is not working?

Correct. There is nothing magical about the <kbd>⌘M</kbd> keyboard shortcut -- it works just like any other menu shortcut. If there is no menu item available in your menubar with that shortcut, nothing will happen when it is pressed.

(The same principle applies to the Edit menu, incidentally. If you remove the Edit menu, standard keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>⌘Z</kbd>, <kbd>⌘X</kbd>, <kbd>⌘C</kbd>, <kbd>⌘V</kbd>, and <kbd>⌘A</kbd> won't work.)

I would strongly advise that you advise your client to reconsider removing standard UI elements from their application. If they don't listen, though, you can add the menu item to another menu, like the application menu.

Comment: Heh, my client didn't even want the *application* menu item - they only reluctantly accepted that because they couldn't agree on any other way of making the About box visible.

Comment: @MusiGenesis You may want to have your client review the HIG, which makes some strong recommendations about the structure of the menu bar: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/menus/menu-bar-menus/

Answer (score 0):

Because your application contains no `Window` menu, there is no menu item with which <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> is associated (ordinarily, it's associated with the `Window` > `Minimize` item). That keyboard shortcut is simply mapped as a shortcut to that menu item's action; delete the item, and its corresponding shortcut is also deleted.

If you want to allow <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> to minimize the window without having a `Minimize` menu action or `Window` menu, you could set up a manual listener in your code that calls the window's `performMiniaturize(_:)` method, which simulates a user manually minimizing a window (as the `Minimize` menu item would). Note that this method is preferable to `miniaturize(_:)`, which does not momentarily highlight the yellow "stoplight" button as is the convention for the <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> shortcut. The code might look something like this:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var keyMonitor: Any?
    ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.keyMonitor = NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyUp) { event -> NSEvent? in
            if (event.modifierFlags.contains(.command)) {
                if (event.keyCode == 46) { // 46 is the key code for "m"
                    self.view.window?.performMiniaturize(nil)
                    return nil
                }
            }
            return event
        }
        ...
    }
...
}
```